# Remove \" characters while returning json

Tags: python, django, json

I'm returning data as a JSON via Python/Django.

I used the below code:

```
jsonObject = serializers.serialize('json', object, fields=('value', 'record_time'))
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(jsonObject), mimetype="application/json")
```

The problem is I'm getting the response as below:

```
"[{\"pk\": null, \"model\": \"model.table\", \"fields\": {\"record_time\": \"2009-11-18T22:45:44Z\", \"value\": 0.6533125480476399}}, {\"pk\": null, \"model\": \"model.table\", \"fields\": {\"record_time\": \"2009-11-19T15:02:15Z\", \"value\": 0.4386133754377899}}]"
```

where as I should be getting it in below format:

```
"[
  {
   "pk": null, 
   "model": "model.table", 
   "fields": 
      {
        "record_time": "2009-11-18T22:45:44Z", 
        "value": 0.6533125480476399
      }
  }, 
  {
    "pk": null, 
    "model": "model.table", 
    "fields": 
      {
        "record_time": "2009-11-19T15:02:15Z", 
        "value": 0.4386133754377899
      }
  }
]"
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: It returns \ to escape double quotes "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are serializing the object into `jsonObject`, but you return the original `object`. Just fix that and everything should work as expected.

**Update:**

Just change your code like this:

```
jsonObject = serializers.serialize('json', object, fields=('value', 'record_time'))
return HttpResponse(jsonObject, mimetype="application/json")
```

The change is the `jsonObject` in the second line.

Comment: The object is a simple `QuerySet` list. How'd I perform what you've said?

Comment: Stackoverflow not allowing so fast. :D

Answer (score 0):

Where you're going wrong is confusing the printed representation of a JSON string with the actual string itself. Those slashes are just the console showing that the double-quotes inside the string are not ending the string, but are part of it. In other words, your JSON is just fine.

Comment: You're right. My JSON is fine. Problem is I'm seeing this on browser and not the beautified part of it. Any leads?