# Inconsistent json serializer in django.core.serializers (unescaped double quotes)

Tags: python, json, django

If I take a simple `ListView`, and wish to return JSON:

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import JsonResponse
class MyListView(ListView):

def get_queryset(self):
    return Thing.objects.all()

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = serializers.serialize("json", self.get_queryset())
    return JsonResponse(data, status=200, safe=False)
```

This will give me "valid" json. However, the json will be delivered like this:

[image: bad json]

It's not only an eyesore, if you then try to print that (eg via `console.log`), those `"""` on lines 2, 8, 11 will become `\"`. (This has been [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30655567/3790954) in other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19023205/3790954)). To parse that json in the browser, you need to run it through `JSON.parse` twice (or transpile the escaped chars another way).

On the other hand, if I do the below code (and this is my present hack for getting around the problem):

```
data = list(map(lambda thing: {"pk": thing.pk, <etc>}, self.get_queryset()))
return JsonResponse(data, status=200, safe=False)
```

This gives me valid json without the additional `"` chars (excuse the cat pic):

[image: good json]

***My question:*** clearly, the browser is getting different inputs. Yes, they're both valid json (they pass validators) - but the first won't clear `JSON.parse()`. Is there any way to force the core serializer to conform to the second json output format? At present I'm having to write a lot of boilerplate serializer code that's making my classes look messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inbuilt django serializer outputs a `String`. The django `JsonpResponse` takes key+value data and stringifies it with the right HTTP headers added. That's fine if you pass a dictionary or list, but if you pass a `String` that aready has `"` chars in it (like the output of the core serializer does), `JsonResponse` blithely escapes the existing `"` because you can't have `"` in an unescaped string of course. Yay teamwork.

Obviously, with this deeper understanding of what's going on, it's a bit stupid to expect the serializer to output anything other than a string - that's what serializers do, right?

So then I might think, can I get the JsonResponse encoder to ignore the `"` somehow in the string? [JsonResponse in 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) can [provide encoder arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

Yes, but none of the arguments include `magically_skip_double_quotes=true`, and even if it did it wouldn't be able to parse `{"quotation": "\"Fine weather!\" said Bob."}` properly.

And at that point, you kind of realise that you actually want to just:

```
from django.forms import model_to_dict
data = [model_to_dict(thing) for thing in things]
```

And that's probably the easiest way of going about it.